How can I write a loop to execute a command for each file as specified by user input?
Below is part of a script to execute a command on a file defined by the variable DSpath. There are several of these files distinguished by the number at the end of the filename "_01". The variable numlongs define how many of these files are present. What is the best way to write a loop which will execute the command for each of these files using the variables? Thank you.
echo How many LONG files exist?

read numlongs

DSpath="$SAMpath"/"$MRN"_EPI-LONG_"$DOM"_01.ds

exec SAMsrc -r"$DSpath" -cGlobal,3-70Hz -W1 -t"$filename"final.max -v


If the file numbers are in ascending order, you can use a for loop in the range of 1 to numlongs.

Which would be for fNum in $(seq 1 $numlongs)  ;  do echo "SAMsrc ... $fNum ..." ; done (I think using exec will mess things up.) If you want to have them run in parallel, post a new question with your looping code as a base.

exec will terminate the current shell and executes the following command instead.

When I run with echo it does print each command correctly with each file I would like to run, but the commands are not actually executed. They are only printed.

Modifying OP's current code to use a for loop:
echo How many LONG files exist?

read numlongs

for ((i=1; i<=numlongs; i++))
do
    printf -v fNum "%02d" $i                                 # left pad with 0 to generate a 2-digit string
    DSpath="${SAMpath}/${MRN_EPI}-LONG_${DOM}_${fNum}.ds"

    SAMsrc -r"$DSpath" -cGlobal,3-70Hz -W1 -t"$filename"final.max -v
done


exec will terminate the current shell and executes the following command instead. So the loop body will be run only once.

Yes, this is what I found when running the loop. Only the 1st file will run.

I ended up writing out the echo file of all the commands to a text file and then using a bash command to execute the commands. This may be a bit round about but it works!

Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by pressing Edit and copy-pasting the actual code you used.
